# Zero pad BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, 64-bit, xampp, jenkins

How can I modify the **BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME** so that is the build number but **zero padded**?

For example, if Jenkins build number is **54**, I would like the name to be **00054**.

Comment: Is this a Jenkins question, or was Jenkins just an example?

Comment: No, it is related to Jenkins. I'm comfortable zero padding numbers in programming but I'm expecting how to do the same thing using Jenkins plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin). During your build you just need to write the build number in the right format to a property file and it will be picked up when the build finishes.

Comment: So that includes manually modifying a file every time a build is done?

Comment: I wouldn't call it manual to have a buildstep that generates the file during your build. Alternative would be to create a plugin that either sets the build number for you or having a plugin that does the formatting for you by having a plugin that extends the token macro plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The Build Name setter is an option, as already reported by Peter Schuetze.
Personally, I have found it a bit cumbersome, so I also use a Groovy System script (from the [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin)) with the following snippet (e.g. set the build name from the Build paramters, which is not related to the actual question, I know):

```
def resolver = build.buildVariableResolver
build.setDisplayName(build.displayName+"_"+resolver.resolve("BUILD_TYPE"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following advice from @patrice-m, I used the [Scriptler](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin) plugin, and created the following script:

```
return String.format("%04d", Thread.currentThread().executable.getNumber());
```

Also, I make sure to activate both **Permission** and **Restriction** checkboxes, which will allow the script to be run by everybody, and on a Master thread (necessary to access the current build).